# how to get value of a node where a leaf is dropped in a tree

Tags: javascript, tree, drag-and-drop, extjs4, treenode

I have a tree panel where a leaf can be dropped to a node. I want to get the value of that node where the leaf is dropped.

Doing this gets me the first node and not the node where I dropped the leaf

```
Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('myStore').tree.root.childNodes[0].get('nodeName')
```

I also tried

```
overModel.get('nodeName')
```

but this doesn't work when the node is expanded..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listeners: {
    drop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition,  dropFunction,  eOpts ){
         console.log(data.records[0].parentNode.data);//old parent 
         console.log( overModel.parentNode.data);//new parent
     } 
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you Khaled... I already have a beforedrop: listener... Should I remove that or are they going to work well together

Comment: You can keep it , they can work together , or replace 'drop' by 'beforedrop'